# What is time and memory complexity of R+tree operations?

Tags: database, geospatial

What is time and memory complexity of R+tree operations?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the time complexity in Big O notation of `R-tree` [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree):

```
Search: O(logMn), Insert: O(n)
```

Here `M` is the Max number of entries each page can contain.